# A query on P and E cores of the new Intel Processors

Tags: virtualbox, cpu, intel-core-i7

Intel, last year came up with this idea of 2 types of cores within the same die, power cores and efficiency cores.

My question is how does the difference translate to some of the VM, containers and other workloads?

Like, if possible, could someone with such a CPU share with me the core allocation page from VirtualBox?

I am interested to know how such cores work and perform, I already know there is no hyper-threading for the E-cores.

But do they even appear in the VirtualBox or for container workloads, or they are not for virtualization purposes, if they do, how do they perform compared to the P cores?

Asking this in context to only the desktop space, I wish to upgrade some of my old servers and I got good deals on my local retailer for the 12th gen.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: The idea of efficiency cores have existed for more than a decade on the ARM architecture

Comment: That's right, and I was about to mention it into the post but thought it would be irrelevant. Anyway, the idea of VMs and container workloads hasn't been around on those ARM based chips, the idea of leveraging the big or LITTLE cores, and how differently they would behave in case of running VMs on 2 different cores, which is the point of primary concern here. Anyway, I'm not interested in ARM and it's a distraction going on to that path here right now. @Ramhound

Comment: I am not aware of any x86 Hypervisors that would treat P-Core and E-Cores differently at this time.

Comment: VMware workstation will default to all efficiency cores, if present.  There are several threads on the vmware communities site regarding this.  Vbox has a different scheduler so it may behave differently.  I don't use VBox, so I can't test.  A Search on the vbox forums only showed a thread from 2021 where the mod hadn't heard of p and e cores...

Comment: Thank you @essjae